# datasource select command wont change with radio buttonlist

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

So based on what is selected in a radiobuttonlist i want the select command to change for my datasource. The problem I'm facing is that if i set the default selected radio button the query will work for that

my radiobuttonlist , user (dropdownlist are all located in an update panel that is not updated after the button is clicked

this my button code

```
    If user.Text = "ALL" Then
                    SqlDataSource22.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [dashboardtasks] WHERE [completed] = 'NO'"
                    SqlDataSource23.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [dashboardtasks] WHERE (([agent] = @agent) AND (([completed] = 'YES') or ([completed] = 'XL')))"
                Else
                    If RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 0 Then
                        SqlDataSource22.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [dashboardtasks] WHERE (([agent] = @agent) AND ([completed] = @completed))"
                        SqlDataSource23.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [dashboardtasks] WHERE (([agent] = @agent) AND (([completed] = 'YES') or ([completed] = 'XL')))"

                    ElseIf RadioButtonList1.SelectedIndex = 1 Then
                        SqlDataSource22.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [dashboardtasks] WHERE (([agent] = @agent) AND ([completed] = @completed) and tasktype = 'Air')"
                        SqlDataSource23.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM [dashboardtasks] WHERE (([agent] = @agent) AND (([completed] = 'YES') or ([completed] = 'XL')) and tasktype = 'Air')"
                    End If
                End If

   UpdatePanel1.Update()
        UpdatePanel2.Update()





<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server"> </asp:ScriptManager>
                              <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel5" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
                                  <ContentTemplate>
                                      <asp:Panel ID="Panel9" runat="server" Height="24px" Width="392px">
                                          <asp:DropDownList ID="ddivision" runat="server" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddivision_SelectedIndexChanged">
                                  <asp:ListItem Selected="True">All</asp:ListItem>
                                  <asp:ListItem Value="A">Club ABC</asp:ListItem>
                                  <asp:ListItem Value="B">ABC Destinations</asp:ListItem>
                              </asp:DropDownList>
                              <asp:DropDownList ID="userslist" runat="server"  Height="20px" Width="184px"></asp:DropDownList>
                      <asp:Button ID="updatediary" runat="server" Text="Update" /></asp:Panel>
                              <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatColumns="5" >
                                  <asp:ListItem>All</asp:ListItem>
                                  <asp:ListItem Selected="True">Land</asp:ListItem>
                                  <asp:ListItem>Air</asp:ListItem>
                                  <asp:ListItem>Cruise</asp:ListItem>
                              </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                  </ContentTemplate>
                                  <Triggers>
                                      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddivision" />
                                  </Triggers>
                              </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I bet your `radiobuttonlist` is not in the `updatepanel` and that's why it is not updated. To update the `radiobuttonlist`, you need to put it in an `updatepanel`.

You need to specify the event Name of the control: `Event="SelectedIndexChanged"`

```
<Triggers>
  <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddivision" Event="SelectedIndexChanged" />
</Triggers>
```

Comment: i tryed that it didnt work, im even updateing the panel using autopostback for the radiobuttonlist and dropdownlist

Comment: Can you post your complete form design?

Comment: anything to help me solve this problem its driving me nuts lol

Comment: Modify answer, try now. if problem remains, post your complete c# code aw well.

Comment: Error 7 Literal content ('<asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddivision" Event="SelectedIndexChanged" / />') is not allowed within a 'System.Web.UI.UpdatePanelTriggerCollection'.

Comment: Remove trigger part completely and check <Triggers>
     <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="ddivision" Event="SelectedIndexChanged" />
 </Triggers>

Comment: Error 7 Type 'System.Web.UI.AsyncPostBackTrigger' does not have a public property named 'Event'.